# How to add additional portals to my DNN community edition site?

Tags: dotnetnuke, host, portal

I know this is a very basic question - I have googled and every where it says - click the "Add New Portal" button/link on the Portals page.

However, I have a DNN community edition version 06.00.00 that is live and I do not see any option to add a new portal. Could this be a configuration issue? Do I have to change some settings to be able to get the option to add a new portal?

See the image of the Host menu and Portals page. I am unable to get the Add New Portal link:
[image: Host menu that I see on hover of Host link on the header bar - I am logged into the host account.]

[image: Here is the portals listing page. Why do I not see the Add New Portal link here?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the menu shown in your first screenshot, you need to go to "Portals"
- Then you will see a small semi-transparent button that says "Manage"(if not, make sure your view mode is set to "Edit" in the top right of the control bar
- hover over it and a menu will drop-down and there will be your "add new site" or "add new portal" link

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure your page is in the EDIT view mode (selected in the top right of the page), then you will see a manage button appear when you hover over the sites on the portal page.  Click the manage button and choose new site.